# How to get kendo ui grid sort event?

Tags: kendo-ui

I currently have a Kendo-UI grid.  It has a few column where user can sort on, works great.  I also have a details link on each row, so if the user clicks on this they are taken to a details page.  I need to pass the current sort into the details page as a value. How can I get the current sort? is there an event I can bind to?
Thanks

Comment: If the link is what triggers showing the details, why do not get current sort on there?

Comment: but how do I know which column sort has been clicked? if its descending or ascending? ie If I have 4 columns. I sort on Column 3 desc. how do I know that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the sorting configuration whenever you want using [sort method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-sort).

Example: Being `grid` the `id` of your Grid. Do:

```
// Get the grid object
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Get the datasource bound to the grid
var ds = grid.dataSource;
// Get current sorting
var sort = ds.sort();
// Display sorting fields and direction
if (sort) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
        alert ("Field:" + sort[i].field + " direction:" + sort[i].dir);
    }
} else {
    alert("no sorting");
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for.. thank you for that.  Do you know how to get the value of the row number of a clicked row? if I click on the 5th row for it to alert 5.. or if I go to the 4th page and click on the 5th item for it to alert 45?

Comment: As a general recommendation, you should not ask a new question in a comment since the chances for others to read it are pretty low. Said that, you should use `dataSource.indexOf` of the item corresponding to the clicked row, and you know the row using something like `grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));` inside the handler of the `click` event.

Comment: Cool, the only issue with that is once the sort has been applied the id is still the same.  I would have expected the first item to be index of 1.  But when the items are sorted by desc the first item is 1200.  I   just want a row number for each row regardless of the sort. thanks for that I will post this up as a new discussion. But it is so hard to post a question on stack flow.  It keeps saying the question does not pass their validation.

Comment: I got it to work by doing the following.  var rowValue = $(e.target).closest("tr").index() + 1;
        var page = (ds._page - 1) * ds._pageSize;

        var currentItem = rowValue + page; where ds is the data source.  It works.  Is this ok? or is there a better method?

Comment: Is there an event that is fired when a column has been sorted?

Comment: @jtromans, not sure if this is what you are looking for, check [columnReorder](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-columnReorder)

Comment: @OnaBai Thanks but this is when the order of the columns is changed. I meant when the column is sorted from, say, ASC to DESC.

Comment: @jtromans then there is no specific event, you should use `dataBound`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this need today and learned that the event is now present as of  2016 R3 release (2016.3.914).

Example usage:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" }
 ],
dataSource: {
  data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
     ],
     schema: {
       model: { id: "id" }
     }
   },
   sortable: true,
    sort: function(e) {
      console.log(e.sort.field);
      console.log(e.sort.dir);
    }
  });
</script>
```

See: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-sort